# Iterate through an array, testing that EVERY element is larger than a certain number

Tags: java, arrays

I've got a really clunky way to do it. But wanted to figure out a leaner looped method. I want to go through my array, and test every element is above a certain value. in this case say, 50.

Heres what I've got:

```
boolean found0 = false;
for (int k = 0; k < array.length ; k++) {
  if (array[0] >= 50 &&
      array[1] >= 50 &&
      array[2] >= 50 &&
      array[3] >= 50 &&
      array[4] >= 50 &&
      array[5] >= 50) {
    found0 = true;
  }
}
```

Comment: Use the increasing value of k as the index in your conditional.

Comment: You have to change:if (array[0]>=50 && array..... for if (array[k] >= 50)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since your iterating variable is called `k`, you can check the `k`th element in the array for >= 50.

If some of the array elements is less than 50, we can set the flag to `false` and break the loop.

```
boolean ok = false;
for (int k = 0; k < array.length ; k++) {
    if (array[k] >= 50) {
        ok = true;     
    } else {
        ok = false;
        break; //Break the loop, because we have at least one, which is < 50
    }
}
```

Even better, we can get shorten the `if/else` statement and check if we have at least one element, less than 50.

```
boolean ok = true;
for (int k = 0; k < array.length; k++) {
   if (array[i] < 50) {
       ok = false;
       break;
   }
}
```

Comment: You should probably `break` once `found0` is set to `true`.

Comment: I assumed if i check array[k] it would check that element was higher than 50 not ALL elements are higher than 50, together.. every element has to be greater than 50

Comment: Check **carefully** the `if/else` statement.

Answer (score 1):

These kinds of tests are best encapsulated in a method.  You can use the simple "for each" loop:

```
private boolean areAllElementsAtLeast(int[] array, int value) {
    for(int i : array) {
        if (i < value) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

For your example you would call it like this:

```
if (areAllElementsAtLeast(array, 50)) {
    // All elements in the array are >= 50
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Do like this

```
boolean found0 = true;
for (int k:array){
    if (!(k >= 50)){
       found0 = false;  
       break;        
    }
}
```